# Adapt ArrayList into Custom ListView

Tags: listview, arraylist

I read data from my database and put it into a ArrayList:

```java
public List<ProcessObject> getAllDeadlines(){

    List<ProcessObject> processObjectList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DATABASE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    ProcessObject processObject;
    cursor.moveToFirst();
            while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
                processObject = cursorToProcessObject(cursor);
                processObjectList.add(processObject);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ID: " + processObject.getId()+ ", Content (title): " + processObject.getTitle());
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
    cursor.close();

    return  processObjectList;
}
```

Now I want to adapt the object list into a customized ListView. But how do I extract the attributes of the Objects from the ArrayList to refer them to the TextViews from the Custom ListView?

So far my code is:

```java
public void showAllDeadlines() {
    List<ProcessObject> list = datasource.getAllDeadlines();

    ArrayAdapter<ProcessObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ProcessObject>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            list);
    DeadlineListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    DeadlineListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The List shows Objects like `ProcessObject@f8f92j23`.
I assume this happens because I have no return statement in my `ProcessObject` class:

```java
public class ProcessObject {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String deadline;

    public ProcessObject(int id, String title, String description, String deadline){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDeadline(){
        return deadline;
    }
    public void setDeadline(String deadline){
        this.deadline = deadline;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
private void displayListView() {
    Cursor cursor = datasource.fetchAllData();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = {
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TITLE,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
            DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DEADLINE,
    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[] {
            R.id.processobject_title,
            R.id.processobject_description,
            R.id.processobject_deadline,
    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.listview_viewlayout,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    activateAddButton();
};
```

datasource:

```
public Cursor fetchAllData(){
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_DATABASE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;
}
```